# error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

estoy empezando en java y estoy creando un método que calcule la potencia de un número real elevado a un entero,pero me sale error al compilar.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     public static double potencia (double base, int exp){
        double pot = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<= exp; i++){
            pot = pot * base;

        }
        return pot;

    }
}
```

Comment: eh.. hay una funcion dentro de otra funcion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes crer un método dentro del método main.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Aquí llamas al método potencia pasandole sus parametros y guarda en una //variable 
    para ver el resultado.
    //Ejemplo:
    double resultado= potencia(tuNumeroDouble, tuNumeroEntero);    
    System.out.println(resultado);
 }
```

Lo correcto sería lo siguiente.

```
public static double potencia (double base, int exp){
        int pot = 1;
        pot = (int) Math.pow(base, exp);
        return pot;
    }//Fin del método potencia
```

Comment: Gracias x la respuesta, igual me sale un error al cerrar, en el fin del método potencia

Comment: Si, perdona era porque el return estaba dentro de for, ya la he editado.

Comment: Gracias ahora si me imprime bien, pero siempre me imprime solo el numero double?
double resultado= potencia(1.5, 2);
siempre imprimirá 1.5?

Comment: Marca como solucionada mi respuesta entonces. Te sabes la formula para sacar la potencia de un número?.

Comment: La he modificado la clase Math contiene un método para sacar la potencia de un número. Ejemplo pasas por parametro (2, 3) el resultado será un 8.0